# Manual prediction of Gaussian Regression SVM in Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm

I trained a SVM using the Regression Learner of Matlab with a Gaussian kernel. The learning worked really well and the RSE is small.

Now, I exported the model back to the Matlab workspace (`trainedModel`) and I can use the `predict` function to get the estimation of new values. However, I would like to manually implement the prediction function, because I need to export it to a different programming language, thus I cannot rely on the Matlab's `predict` function. Therefore, following the [MATLAB explanation](https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/understanding-support-vector-machine-regression.html) I implemented the following equation:

[image]

with

[image]

This is my code for a [0.5 1 50] input:

```
bias  = trainedModel.RegressionSVM.Bias;
alpha = trainedModel.RegressionSVM.Alpha;
SV    = trainedModel.RegressionSVM.SupportVectors;
Mu    = trainedModel.RegressionSVM.Mu;
Sg    = trainedModel.RegressionSVM.Sigma;

input = ([0.5 1 50] - Mu) ./ Sg;
sum = bias;
for n=1:length(alpha)
    G = exp(-norm((SV(n,:)'-input))^2);
    sum = sum + alpha(n) .* G;
end
disp(sum)
```

(Note that `alpha` is already the difference of the Lagrangian multipliers according to the documentation)

However, the predicted results are completely wrong. I think something is wrong with `G` because the values are very small (in the order of 10^(-25)), but I cannot figure out the error.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was very small... The reason is the transposition of the SV array, which is incorrect (it creates a matrix due to the - operator, but then it's hidden by the norm). Therefore, changing the following line:

```
G = exp(-norm((SV(n,:)'-input))^2);
```

to

```
G = exp(-norm((SV(n,:)-input))^2);
```

solved the problem.